# Determine the relationship between two elements

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have the following DOM elements:

```
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

And let's assume that I have a reference to each div, but not to a collection of them. Is there some way I can determine the relationship between them? E.g., if I have `div1` and `div2`, is there some way I can tell whether `div1` is before or after (or inside, or whatever) `div2`?

I know I can use

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

...and then of course, `elements[0]` is before `elements[1]`. But if I don't have that collection of elements, just individual references, is there a way to tell?

Comment: Can you add ids or classes to the elements?

Comment: This is a theoretical question which came to my mind. So, no change of DOM.

Comment: Could you describe what your end goal is? And maybe the reason why the array index isn't sufficient?

Comment: Your css seems to be irrelevant to what you are asking.

Comment: @Stack0verflow I think the point is that the divs will overlap - ie you can't use their position to identify them

Comment: @JamesThorpe that makes sense.

Comment: @ James Thorpe. Yes. That's why I added the CSS

Comment: @CharlieH and my questions? If you want a decent answer you are going to need to give us more information. What you are trying to accomplish, your limitations and the reason for them.

Comment: @AndrewB This is a theoretical question. The aim is to find unique property values of element[0] and element[1] in this circumstance.

Comment: So use the index or an id, or classes. These things were invented to solve the issue of differentiating between elements. Why are you intentionally ignoring them and vaguly asking for another way? And then downvoting every answer people offer without telling us why they are wrong?

Comment: I'm intentionally ignoring id or classes because I need to find a way identifying elements without them. And I down voted only one answer which talks about something other than what I asked.

Comment: Okay so please add that into your original question so people have more information and can attempt to help you better. Finally, why can't you use any form of array indexing? Are loops out of the question also?

Comment: Anyone who sees my css part can understand what I'm looking for. Please see James Thorpe's comment.

Comment: If that was true you would have an answer by now. That is the first piece of constructive feedback you have given to anyone's solutions or feedback. If you aren't going to help us help you, your question will stay with negative votes and be ignored by anyone that could actually have the answer you want.

Comment: What more help do you need? I said I'm checking if there is a way to uniquely identify DOM elements without id, class etc? Do you need my b'day too? :)

Comment: So basically, you want an answer, but if you get one it's wrong. If I submit an answer saying "No." will you accept my answer and be done with this preposterous question?

Comment: If you include the proof of that "No" in the answer, I wouldn't hesitate to accept it fully!

Comment: @ AndrewB -  Please see the accepted answer. There maybe things which exist beyond the limits you can see.

Comment: @CharlieH everyone here in some way has stated that your question is unclear, the accepted answer and the other saying his answer is a "shot in the dark". The problem is how you asked it, how we had to constantly probe you for feedback rather than you providing the information to begin with.

Comment: The edit is far more intuitive, so I changed my vote. Have a good day.

Comment: Not we - you had to constantly probe me for more information - which the accepted answer didn't want. That's why I said everyone has their limits. Good day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, now you've said the question is about JavaScript, and you want to know how to "distinguish" between the two divs without using their position in the collection (`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an actual array, just something very array-like). The only reason I can think of for doing that is if you don't have the collection, you just have references to the two divs and want to know which comes first in the document.

You could, of course, *get* the collection and then look for the divs inside it, but you can also use [`compareDocumentPosition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-compareDocumentPosition) (that links to the spec, which isn't as clear as it might be; [here's the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)). `compareDocumentPosition` tells you where the element you call it on is relative to the element you pass into it:

- DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED (1)
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING (2)
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING (4)
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS (8)
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY (16)
- DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC (32)

E.g.:

```
if (oneDiv.compareDocumentPosition(theOtherDiv) & 2) {
    // oneDiv is prior to theOtherDiv in the document order
} else {
    // could be any of the others, but if we assume that both
    // are actually in the document and that neither contains
    // the other, then theOtherDiv is prior to oneDiv
}
```

Example:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('div');
theoreticalFunction("0, 1", list[0], list[1]);
theoreticalFunction("1, 0", list[1], list[0]);
snippet.log(" "); // Just to move past the divs

function theoreticalFunction(label, oneDiv, theOtherDiv) {
  snippet.log(label);
  // 2 = "preceding"
  if (oneDiv.compareDocumentPosition(theOtherDiv) & 2) {
    snippet.log("theOtherDiv is prior to oneDiv in the document order");
  } else {
    // We're assuming it's following, but of course, there are lots
    // of other possible values:
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED 1
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING 2
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING 4
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS 8
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY 16
    // DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC 32
    snippet.log("oneDiv is prior to theOtherDiv in the document order");
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<p id="spacer"></p>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

**Original answer when the question seemed to be about CSS:**

It *sounds* like you're trying to do this

1. In CSS, and
2. Without adding any other identifying features to the elements

I don't believe you can unless they're in the same parent (or of course, if one of them were inside the other, but that's not what you've shown), or unless you can refer to their parent/ancestor elements (which we can't in answers, because there are none in the question).

If they're in the same parent, you have two options:

If they're really as you've shown them, right next to each other, you can distinguish them using the *[adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators)*, `+`:

```
div + div {
    /* Styles for second div */
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}

div + div {
  top: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

If they're not actually adjacent, you can use the [*general sibling combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `~`.

```
div ~ div {
    /* Styles for latter div */
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}

div ~ div {
  top: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
<p>Something in-between</p>
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: This is great. This is what I was looking for. My observation was that elements[0] === elements[1] returns false.

Comment: @CharlieH: Glad that helped. I've edited the question to try to make it ask what I think we eventually figured out was the question, including removing the CSS red herring. If I've got it wrong, though, please adjust as necessary.

Comment: I think it should be `if (oneDiv.compareDocumentPosition(theOtherDiv) & 2)` as it returns a bitmask.

Comment: @Winchestro: Ah, you're quite right. Certain combinations can indeed fit multiple criteria, like "preceding" and "contains".

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here, but what's wrong with:

```js
var same = elements[0] === elements[1]; // false
var same2 = elements[0] === elements[0]; // true
```

-KB

Comment: okay good, well I noticed that even when I use two different variables: var divs1 = document.querySelectorAll('div'); var divs2 = document.querySelectorAll('div'); that divs1[0] === divs2[0] would be true